# How do master detail objects work in OOP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, business-objects

I am currently designing a master detail gridview. I have two separate objects defined for them. The parent gridview is binded to the first object and in row databind event I bind the second gridview with the detail object using parent ID.

A lot of examples I see on the internet initialize the details object inside the parent class,

```
public class Author
{

    private string name;
    public BooksList books=new BooksList();

    public BooksList Books
    {
       get
    { 
       return emailAddresses;
    }
    set
    {
       emailAddresses = value;
    }
}
```

> 1. What is the purpose of initializing child class inside the
>      parent class?
> 2. Currently, I just bind the parent to a separate object & child to a
>      separate object manually in my presentation layer & never initialize child objects inside parent class. Is that the wrong way
>      for OOP ?
> 3. What is the recommended way to achieve this task for my gridview?

Damien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Most of the time you want to initialize you objects inside of your class to avoid null reference issues.

2: You confusing you concepts here, as how you present your objects is not really relevant to OOP.  The OOP part of the equation is all about what your classes are and how they relate to each other, so yes if there is a relationship between the parent and child classes, then it should be represented in the class structures.

3:  Ideally, you would have a class structure that allows you to bind to your datagrid and can automatically generate your hierarchy for your datagrid.

Comment: Thank you Brent. Yep, I think Null references are a big plus point. Currently my objects don't relate to each other, I just relate them via presentation logic.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered that an Author is not/should not be responsible for maintaining a list of his/her books? What books? Whas (s)he the sole author or a co-author? How would you solve that?

May I suggest a "Library" class which has a list of books in its care, which you can check out, and check in, etc. Each book has one or more author references. You could instantiate these in the book class, but I think it would be better if they were references (in)to the Library's list of authors. That way each author only exists once, instead of having an instance in each and every book (s)he has (co-)written.

Comment: Hi Marjan, its just an example. Would the child list object be initialized in master class object always ? Currently I am just displaying objects through presentation logic and the list class books is not initialized in author class object.

Comment: "Always" is like "never" and according to Sean Connery: "Never say never again..." (Sorry). But really, it depends. Yes, the parent would normally instantiate the child, but when is another matter. If instantiation is just that you usually are fine. If instantiation also involves loading from a data store, then loading the lists for each and every author could make for horrendous loadtimes. Look into "Lazy loading"/"Lazy instantiation" for counter measures. Also, instantiation and/or loading at instantiation can raise interesting problems when you have circular references between classes...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Marjan. I will look into things you said. Damien.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to enforce that all authors have a booklist (empty or not) everytime then you do it like this. Otherwise if you want to consider having a null as BookList in many cases to avoid creating unneeded empty objects then you can create the Booklist separetly and inject a specific booklist instance it into the authors via the constructor when the case requires it, or set it later using the setter when depending on your necessities.